# What logic should I apply for printing even and odd number of an array without using arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays

The logic I applied was:

- Looping though the given array and keeping the count of number of even and odd numbers in array.
- Suppose "n" is number of even numbers and "m" is number of odd numbers in the array.
- After that making two arrays of size "n" and "m" and storing even and odd numbers in those array and displaying both arrays.

Is this logic right? Because I'm having problem in writing code. If anyone can help.

Comment: Do you have an array of int, ie `int[]`? And what relevance has `ArrayList`?

Comment: Can you show us an example of your code and what about it is not working?

Comment: Hello, do you want to create two arrays of int, one for odd numbers and one for even numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t use `ArrayList` (presumably homework), then use `LinkedList` instead!

```
List<Integer> odds = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> evens = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
        evens.add(array[i]);
    } else {
        odds.add(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Then print the contents of the lists as you like.